# How do I configure Androids sdkmanager command line tool to use custom repository?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

Is it possible to configure Google's Android sdkmanager to download dependencies through a custom repository instead of `dl.google.com/android/repository`?

**Background:**

I'm setting up an Android build agent behind a corporate firewall with no direct Internet access. I can access a repository server on LAN that acts as a mirror to pre-configured remote repositories.

I've downloaded SDK Tools from here `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip`

On a machine with Internet access I've tried to configure `~/.android/repositories.cfg` like this:

```
### User Sources for Android Repository
#Fri Nov 30 12:36:38 CET 2018
enabled00=true
count=1
disp00=DB Artifactory
src00=https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml
```

Which is the configuration I get if I set up a custom SDK Update Site in Android Studio.

The xml file downloaded here is exactly the same as configured by Android Studio - and its also the same I observe with Charles Proxy when running the sdkmanager command line tool.

It works just fine for the default "Android Repository" configuration in Android Studio, but my custom configuration fails both in Android Studio and from the command line.

I see this error:

```
Step 25/34 : RUN yes | sdkmanager --licenses --proxy=http -- 
proxy_host=host.docker.internal --proxy_port=3128
 ---> Running in 8d8923c76ba7
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions - 
XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap
Warning: Errors during XML parse:       ] 42% Downloading sys-img.xml... Parse X
Warning: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'sdk:sdk-repository'.
,,Warning: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 139; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'sdk:sdk-repository'.
Warning: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 139; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'sdk:sdk-repository'.]
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
```

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Creating the file `~/.android/repositories.cfg` and filling it accordingly (as you show) has worked for me with `sdkmanager --version` 26.1.1 from `platform-tools` 31.0.3.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [sdkmanager's source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/tools_r21/sdkmanager/libs/sdkuilib/src/com/android/sdkuilib/internal/repository/UpdaterData.java#370) - there seems to be an alternative method of overriding the repository - via `SDK_TEST_BASE_URL` environment variable:

> For testing, the env var can be set to replace the default root
>   download URL.
>
> It must end with a / and its the location where the
>   updater will look for the repository.xml, addons_list.xml and such
>   files.

Thus, you could do something like this:

```sh
SDK_TEST_BASE_URL=https://your.company/artifactory/android/ sdkmanager "platform-tools"
```

The example above will attempt to install `platform-tools` package using the provided repository URL. 
Just make sure the URL ends with a `/`

Comment: Thanks for your answer - unfortunately we moved away from our artifactory solution so I'm unable to verify :/

Comment: I can verfify that this works. It is unclear however how reliable it is to rely on this, as it is an internal testing variable that might change or be removed in future versions.

Comment: How do we pass credentials to custom artifactory? Would it be:
SDK_TEST_BASE_URL=https: //user:password@your.company/artifactory/android/ sdkmanager "platform-tools"

Comment: @SagarMody yes, that should work, given that your server supports basic authentication.