# What should I change on Android sdkmanager CLI to allow download from artifactory?

Tags: android, artifactory, android-sdk-manager

Hello and thanks for your support.
I'm in a situation where I have to install android sdk cli tools and need to download some extras using sdkmanager, however the build machine doesn't have access to any external resource, only the company's artifactory repo. 
Is there any way to modify sdkmanager to use an artifactory repo instead of the standard dl.google.androi-remote?

I have already tried [How do I configure Androids sdkmanager command line tool to use custom repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610346/how-do-i-configure-androids-sdkmanager-command-line-tool-to-use-custom-repositor) but it didn't work and haven't been able to find more documentation.

Thank you for your time and help.

Edit:The repo is a remote in this format  https://artifactoryserver.com/artifactory/dl.google.android-remote/ and when appending the required tool name in the browser downloads or direct to the correct file. Eg:https://artifactoryserver.com/artifactory/dl.google.android-remote/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip downloads the sdk, or  https://artifactoryserver.com/artifactory/dl.google.android-remote/addon2-1.xml downloads the correct file.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54618642), which explains that you can use something like:

```
export SDK_TEST_BASE_URL="https://artifactoryserver.com/artifactory/dl.google.android-remote/"
sdkmanager --list
```

However, be aware that (at least, in my experience, using the "Generic" repository type) Artifactory will treat all files, including the manifest-style `repository2-1.xml` (etc) as artifacts, and therefore it will cache them indefinitely (within caching limits/rules). That means your `sdkmanager` will not automatically know about any recent changes (such as if a new build-tools version is released, you will not be able to update it in sdkmanager).

In order to clear the cache of the `repository2-1.xml` file in artifactory, thus causing it to re-download the file from Google, you will have to "Zap" the cache (or just delete the file from the mirror in Artifactory's Artifact browser). I haven't found a good way to make Artifactory treat those xml files as manifest/metadata files, which would be useful.

It must be possible, as e.g. the Maven repository layout is able to download updated `maven-metadata.xml` files.